# How to create an array which has three 0s and two 1s in a random permutation in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, random

Wanna create a ruby array which has 5 numbers consist of three 0s and two 1s in a random permutation

such as, [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 ] or [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

I know that

```
 Array.new(5) { rand(2) }
```

could create five random numbers consist of 0 and 1

but how can I make sure there are exactly three 0s and two 1s ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use shuffle.

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1].shuffle

=> [0, 0, 1, 0, 1] # or some other permutation
```